# Parent inform children

Tags: reactjs

I've got a list (parent) with lots of items (children). There's a huge save button on the list. When the user presses that button, I'd like to have all the childrens `save()` method to be fired.

Usually, I'd use a custom event for this (or some PubSub implementation), but I wonder: What's the React.js way to achieve this?

Comment: A better way, even ignoring React, would be for the parent to call the business logic necessary to save the children (ideally as a group). The UI component shouldn't be responsible for "saving." Also, in React, you can't call a method on a child component.

Comment: I thought about something like that, too, but I'll need to have access to almost all of the childrens data (a.k.a. their `state`). Any patterns for that? I'm relatively new to React.js.

Comment: Why not have a container gather the data for each child and provide it to each one? That way, you've centralized the data. Each child would have a reference to the data, but wouldn't "own" it.

Comment: Theoretically, I could use my data store as such a container. But still, I'll need some kind of "event" to tell the children to write their `state` into the store. What other possibilities than keyPress do you see?

Comment: You should let the parent have the state and render children via props as @WiredPrairie mentioned, children should not have a state in my opinion.

Comment: Okay. But my children have input fields. `props` are immutable. Where shall I  save the changes (if they don't have a state)?

Comment: The changes should "bubble" out to your storage, be it Flux, or other modeling system that is maintained within your container.

Comment: Totally agree with the previous comments, and if you need an example, have a look at the "callbacks as props" section of the React tutorial: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#callbacks-as-props

Comment: What do you mean by "bubble" out? And based on what event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent should have the state and render children with props. This is just a example, not tested.

Parent:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
     return {array: []}
},
handleChange: function(key, value){
 // here will you get key and value from child input.
   this.setState({array[key]: value});
}, 
saveAll: function(){
     // this.state.array have all data, lets save it :)
},
render: function(){
     var self = this;
     var items = [];
     this.state.array.map(function(item, key){
           items.push(<Child handleChange={self.handleChange} index={key} value={item} />);
     });
     return (<div>{items} <button onClick={this.saveAll}>SaveAll</button> </div>
}
});
```

Child:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    onChange: function(event){
         this.props.handleChange(this.props.index, event.target.value);
    },
    render: function(){
          return (<li><input value={this.props.value} onChange={this.onChange} />)
    }
});
```